# couldn't add user: Could not lock auth data update lock

Tags: mongodb, authentication, sharding

I am trying to setup authentication on a mongodb shard cluster(1 mongos, 3 mongod, 3 mongo configsvr). I have restarted all the components in the cluster with parameter **--keyFile**, then login via **mongos** to add administrator user in the **admin** database. But encountered this error:

```
mongos> use admin
mongos> db.createUser( 
{ 
   user: "admin", 
   pwd: "admin_password", 
   roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
} )

2015-01-13T22:19:53.882+0800 Error: couldn't add user: Could not lock auth data update lock. 
at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

I did that according the mongodb website's [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-in-sharded-cluster/)

can someone help me out? thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. I tried to catch the same thing happening but failed to do it with either version 2.6.7 or 2.8.0-rc4. I used the [this script](https://gist.github.com/akira-kurogane/fe30701867026ac7d63d) on my linux desktop to create a brand new cluster with the same 3 db nodes, 3 configsvr structure as you. And after I ran that I was able to login with mongos, "use admin", and run that same db.createUser() command without error. So obviously there's a difference somewhere. Could you tell me what version you are using? (I can quickly test different versions)

Comment: @Akira Kurogane Hi, thanks for your attention, my mongodb version is 2.6.3 and I tried simulate the same scenario on my computer, it is worked. The mongos log file says there is a global lock was not released.

Comment: I tried it with 2.6.3, and the user was successfully created. The mongos log output during db.createUser() was  
"[conn2] distributed lock 'authorizationData/.....' acquired, ts : ....  
"[conn2] SyncClusterConnection connecting to ... _(x 3)_  
"[conn2] distributed lock 'authorizationData/.....' unlocked"  
So, despite having the same version I have not recreated the same problem yet. Could you share your whole log file somewhere?